# A (non)-counterexample to Fubini's Theorem

Tags: calculus, integration

I've been trying to tackle the following preliminary exam question:
Consider the function $f:[0,1] \times [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{ R } $ defined by 
$$
 f(x,y) = \left\{ 
  \begin{matrix}
   y^{-2} &  & 0<x<y<1 \\
   - x^{-2} &  & 0<y<x<1 \\
   0 &  & \mathrm{otherwise} \\
   \end{matrix} \right. 
$$
Show by direct computation that 
$$
 \int_{0} ^{1} \left(\int_{0} ^{1} f(x,y) \,dx\right) \,dy \ne \int_{0} ^{1}\left( \int_{0} ^{1} f(x,y) \,dy \right) \,dx
$$
Why does this not contradict Fubini's Theorem?
I believe I see the punchline-the given function does not satisfy the integrability hypotheses necessary to apply Fubini.  For some reason though I'm not sure how to handle the computation.  For the inner integral on the LHS, we hold $y$ constant while we integrate in $x$, but the function $f$ depends on which $y$ value we fix while allowing $x$ to vary.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the left hand side, the inner integral is: $\int_{x=0}^y f(x,y)dx + \int_{x=y}^1 f(x,y)dx$.  Does that help?

Comment: Yes!  Of course.  Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $y$. We may assume $0<y<1$ since the function is zero if $y=0$ or if $y=1$. Since $y$ is fixed, we have that $$\int_0^1 f(x,y)dx = \int_0^y y^{-2} dx + \int_y^1 -x^{-2} dx = \frac{1}{y} + \big(1 - \frac{1}{y} \big)=1$$

hence $$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y)dx dy = 1.$$

For the right hand side, in a similar manner, fix $x$. Then

$$\int_0^1 f(x,y)dy = \int_0^x -x^{-2} dy + \int_x^1 y^{-2} dy=-\frac{1}{x}-\big(1-\frac{1}{x}\big)=-1$$

hence $$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y)dx dy=-1.$$

This is not a contradiction of Fubini's Theorem, since $\int_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}|f(x,y|(dx \times dy)=\infty$ (use Tonelli's Theorem to show this), implying $f(x,y)$ is not integrable over this domain.